# two way binding not working on checkbox in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-grid

datagrid is bound to array.

a checkbox is bound to a property called isSelected

```
                        <input class="checkbox binning-checkbox" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.isSelected" (ngModelChange)="select(dataItem)" >
```

everything goes in array

```
  public selectedData = [];
```

i am trying to set a limit that no more than 15 should be selected so i am trying to uncheck the 16th item is selected.

```
    public select(order, element) {
    this.totalChecked++;
    let index = this.selectedData.indexOf(order);
    if (order.isSelected == true && this.selectedData.length < 15 ) { // && this.selectedData.length < 15 && index === -1

        this.selectedData.push(order);
    }
    else if (order.isSelected == false) { //&& index != -1
        this.selectedData.splice(index, 1);
        this.allSelected = false;
        this.totalChecked--;
        this.totalChecked--;
    }
    else if (this.totalChecked > 15) {
        this.limitExceeded = true;
        order.isSelected = false;
        this.totalChecked--;
    }
}
```

here

```
 order.isSelected = false
```

doesn't deselect the checkbox.

this is a KendoGrid bound like this

```
 <kendo-grid #grid="kendoGrid"  [data]="filteredData" [filter]="state.filter"
```

Comment: I think that the parameter 'order' may not be the same as this.selectedData[index]. Try to set isSelected on that one.

Comment: when checkbox is clicked 16th time the 'order' is not yet in the array. so i can not set it to false that way. 

how ever the object that is received in the 'select' function has isSelected = true at that time